# Who does Hammond answer to?

Tags: stargate

In season 7 a new structure is created called Homeworld Defense with Hammond as its head. This seems to be formed by the US, but must be controlled by a coalition of nations so does this make Hammond sorta like the "President" of Earth and outside of the control of the US? Or what? I don't think it is ever stated but it seems that after season 7 Stargate clearly goes more international which seems to indicate that while the stargate is stationed in the US the program, if not the world of SG is moving more towards a world government.

Other than just these indications are there any explicit details with regards to this?

Comment: I believe he's mentioned as answering to the President directly.  I don't think the IOA (the international coalition of nations) controls Homeworld Defense but rather are part of a treaty that oversees the Stargate/Atlantis/etc.  I think of it sort of like a NATO-like group where the highest ranking US representative (head of Homeworld Defense) is almost certainly going to follow the international consensus... unless they're ordered otherwise.  Which may be politically inadvisable, but fundamentally the President is their superior, not the IOA.

Comment: Not "president", as that'd imply a civilian position or leadership of the world mandate, and he's not, he's still a part of the military chain. @starpilotsix 's comment sounds right; many organizations have a committee with general authority but put the actionables under one position with the burden (and blame) of snap decisions.  I just don't know what we can quote to justify that as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Homeworld Security / Command](http://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/Homeworld_Security) is a branch of the U.S. Department of Defense and a part of the President's Administration, meaning that its leader answers directly to the President of the United States of America, the Commander-In-Chief.

With regards to it being more international, the U.S. is also the primary point of contact for all Stargate operations, a position appointed to them officially by Thor, after convincing various officials from the UK, China and Russia (much to Robert Kinsey's chargrin) that the Stargate is best kept in the hands of the Americans, who are more than happy to risk their own lives and spend their own money on the Stargate program, so other countries don't have to.

So it's all pretty much controlled by the US, but only because the rest of the world has basically agreed that it's America's problem.